# XAdES4j signature verification - URI issues

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, xades4j

I have a problem with signature verification in XAdES format.
I have two files, the original file is in docx format, and the signature is a detached xml file. I think the problem might be associated with the file URI.
Here is my detached signature file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ds:Signature
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Sgn_2804249982172_0">
    <ds:SignedInfo Id="SgnInfo_2804256168581_6">
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        <ds:Reference Id="Ref_2804255147729_3" URI="inwo.docx">
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>+lf+CQUm2Q9AtpgUWtb3t1Es8fw=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
        <ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" Id="Ref_2804256109848_4" URI="#SgnProp_2804250190981_1">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>4Y0jeM8Wra5VbOOKmPyzUymtWdQ=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue Id="SgnVal_2804256158333_5">J1WDOfKDjuMCz3W8sXXJ2+Ez5yF3bBS3vHogdhckiVrX2hw9FxHADknZPDLsOuLP1TrQi3i2ryvyikVAU3TSw1/wTnVNWG92C4hCPLkL+ISpulzr7KB38dWbXjIC2mjEPGUoS2e1r57Vri9M+q46Ivm5eFRGw/N785GLdt+K8ZZjee5VxCI200G/2hgqq8rA/5vibZ1RjyQ5SU+Mrdlmjdlk5lSYfHYBPICAxQCt1kiuNezHwSb0KquQb//iymvijEFnJ9TzX+TvKJNaTnCE6gymJVupmaH+8xZjEN8oRJH/TjnfEdOtzwBZJt/G/Q2e22crv/Y91MlcBBCZYH1gBA==</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo Id="Key_2804250972666_2">
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    <ds:Object>
        <xades:QualifyingProperties
            xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="#Sgn_2804249982172_0">
            <xades:SignedProperties Id="SgnProp_2804250190981_1">
                <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                    <xades:SigningTime>2015-06-29T10:50:04Z</xades:SigningTime>
                    <xades:SigningCertificate>
                        <xades:Cert>
                            <xades:CertDigest>
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                                <ds:DigestValue>v+nTdfEy11gU0HuH7HHr/YZvx6c=</ds:DigestValue>
                            </xades:CertDigest>
                            <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=CenCert Centrum Certyfikatów Kwalifikowanych,O=Enigma SOI sp. z o.o.,C=PL,SERIALNUMBER=Nr wpisu: 11</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                <ds:X509SerialNumber>555071669451980044</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                            </xades:IssuerSerial>
                        </xades:Cert>
                    </xades:SigningCertificate>
                </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                <xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
                    <xades:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#Ref_2804255147729_3">
                        <xades:MimeType>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document</xades:MimeType>
                    </xades:DataObjectFormat>
                </xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
            </xades:SignedProperties>
        </xades:QualifyingProperties>
    </ds:Object>
</ds:Signature>
```

And here is my stacktace exception :

```
xades4j.XAdES4jXMLSigException: Error verifying the signature
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.doCoreVerification(XadesVerifierImpl.java:285) ~[xades4j-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:188) ~[xades4j-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at pl.comp.kbf.services.ejb.repository.pki.DigitalSignVerifierServiceImpl.verifyFileSignature(DigitalSignVerifierServiceImpl.java:99) ~[KBFPortalEJB.jar/:na]
    at pl.comp.kbf.services.ejb.repository.pki.DigitalSignVerifierServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.verifyFileSignature(Unknown Source) [KBFPortalEJB.jar/:na]
    at pl.comp.kbf.portal.documents.registered.FileSignatureBean.verifyXAdESSignature(FileSignatureBean.java:231) [FileSignatureBean.class:na]
    at pl.comp.kbf.portal.documents.registered.FileSignatureBean.verifySignature(FileSignatureBean.java:195) [FileSignatureBean.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289) [javax.el.jar:3.0.1-b03]
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304) [javax.el.jar:3.0.1-b03]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-osgi-bundle.jar:2014-06-18 10:59]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-osgi-bundle.jar:2014-06-18 10:59]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [javax.faces.jar:2.2.7]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87) [javax.faces.jar:2.2.7]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) [javax.faces.jar:2.2.7]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [javax.faces.jar:2.2.7]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790) [javax.faces.jar:2.2.7]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282) [javax.faces.jar:2.2.7]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [javax.faces.jar:2.2.7]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [javax.faces.jar:2.2.7]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [javax.faces.jar:2.2.7]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [javax.faces.jar:2.2.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:105) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:205) [rewrite-servlet-2.0.12.Final.jar:2.0.12.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:873) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpRewriteResultHandler.handleResult(HttpRewriteResultHandler.java:41) [rewrite-servlet-2.0.12.Final.jar:2.0.12.Final]
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.rewrite(RewriteFilter.java:268) [rewrite-servlet-2.0.12.Final.jar:2.0.12.Final]
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:188) [rewrite-servlet-2.0.12.Final.jar:2.0.12.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673) [web-core.jar:na]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99) [web-glue.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282) [web-core.jar:na]
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459) [kernel.jar:na]
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167) [kernel.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.signature.MissingResourceFailureException: The Reference for URI inwo.docx has no XMLSignatureInput
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Manifest.verifyReferences(Manifest.java:414) ~[xmlsec-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.SignedInfo.verify(SignedInfo.java:259) ~[xmlsec-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.checkSignatureValue(XMLSignature.java:724) ~[xmlsec-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.checkSignatureValue(XMLSignature.java:656) ~[xmlsec-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.doCoreVerification(XadesVerifierImpl.java:278) ~[xades4j-1.3.1.jar:na]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.signature.ReferenceNotInitializedException: Could not find a resolver for URI inwo.docx and Base null
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.calculateDigest(Reference.java:726) ~[xmlsec-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.verify(Reference.java:761) ~[xmlsec-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Manifest.verifyReferences(Manifest.java:336) ~[xmlsec-1.5.1.jar:na]
    ... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.signature.ReferenceNotInitializedException: Could not find a resolver for URI inwo.docx and Base null
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.dereferenceURIandPerformTransforms(Reference.java:621) ~[xmlsec-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.calculateDigest(Reference.java:705) ~[xmlsec-1.5.1.jar:na]
    ... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.signature.ReferenceNotInitializedException: Could not find a resolver for URI inwo.docx and Base null
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.getContentsBeforeTransformation(Reference.java:434) ~[xmlsec-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.dereferenceURIandPerformTransforms(Reference.java:614) ~[xmlsec-1.5.1.jar:na]
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Could not find a resolver for URI inwo.docx and Base null
    at org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver.getInstance(ResourceResolver.java:124) ~[xmlsec-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver.getInstance(ResourceResolver.java:183) ~[xmlsec-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.getContentsBeforeTransformation(Reference.java:417) ~[xmlsec-1.5.1.jar:na]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `useDataForAnonymousReference`, but the file reference **is not anonymous**. On anonymous references the URI attribute is omitted (you can have at most one of such references in a signature).

For your use-case (relative URIs) you should [define the base URI](https://code.google.com/p/xades4j/wiki/ResolvingSignedResources#Base_URI_for_relative_references) for relative references using `SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions.useBaseUri()`. The supplied URI should be a file URI for a local dir.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, URI issues are a bit tough to deal with.

Despite that, looking at the code you pasted,

```
<ds:Reference Id="Ref_2804255147729_3" URI="inwo.docx">
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>+lf+CQUm2Q9AtpgUWtb3t1Es8fw=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
```

This is the reference to the docx file, which points to either:

- root\inwo.docx
- [Same folder where the xml detached signature is]\inwo.docx.

Try placing both files on the same folder and run the verification. If despite of that it does not work, you could manually check whether the signature is correct, by checking the hashes. Then the problem would rely on how XAdES4j works when verifying, and you could try checking their libraries javadocs to see how to correctly proceed.

Comment: But I use this : 

`SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions options = new SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions().useDataForAnonymousReference(file);
xadesVerifier.verify(signatureNode, options);
` where the `file` is my original file input stream